# Аттестат о, об, по?

Tags: грамматика

Как лучше написать в переведённом документе: аттестат по квалификационным экзаменам, аттестат о квалификационных экзаменах или аттестат об квалификационных экзаменах?

В российских документах есть только аттестат об образовании, но в оригинале документа это именно аттестат по экзаменам.

Comment: Мне кажется что вы в 3м варианте зря добавили `Б` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему, перевод должен быть не пословный, а стандартный - должно быть терминологически верное название документа.

Если это школьный документ, то "Аттестат о среднем образовании" или "об основном образовании", чуть раньше писали "о неполном среднем образовании". Если это аттестат по итогам квалификационных экзаменов по профессии, то его название "Квалификационный аттестат специалиста ..." и называется специальность. Если Вы назовёте его по-другому, он может быть недействительным.

Но если уж необходим пословный перевод, тогда  *"Аттестат по итогам квалификационных экзаменов"*. Аттестатов об экзаменах я не видела.

Comment: Будет ли документ действительным - я уточню у нотариуса. Сейчас важно выбрать вариант, соответствующий нормам русского языка. Пока мне нравится вариант "Аттестат по итогам квалификационных экзаменов".

Comment: "Аттестат по итогам" выглядит не совсем убедительно: _по итогам_ специалиста можно "аттестовать" или "не аттестовать" (аттестуют в таких случаях человека), в то время как аттестат должен удостоверять некий _названный_ уровень квалификации или говорить об _успешном_ прохождении экзаменов на квалификацию.

Comment: Просто в нашей стране в  образовательной практике используется вариант "аттестат о таком-то образовании"(документ об окончании учебного заведения), аттестат о получении звания (профессора, например) или "квалификационный аттестат специалиста". Других названий у документа нет. Устаревшие значения - аттестат как свидетельство о  прохождении службы в дореволюционной России и рекомендация с места прежней службы. Есть ещё аттестат   как документ о получении довольствия. Так что аттестат по итогам квалификационных экзаменов будет грамотен с точки зрения норм языка, но чужд нашей практике.